# How can I read the data from file into the index for a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays

my data looks like:

```
1 2 3
1 3 7
2 1 6
4 3 8
```

I hope to get an array c[i][j] that the first col of the data is [i], the second col is [j], and the value goes into the array.

And I am new to java, I read sth about file input, like:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Words {
    public static void main(String[] args)
       throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
       processFile("words.txt");
    }

    public static void processFile(String filename)
      throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
      while (true) {
          String s = in.readLine();
          if (s == null) break;
            System.out.println(s);
          }
      }
    }
```

Is their a good way to change the code into what I want?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what exactly you are trying to do with that 2D array. Could you be more specific?

Maybe more of data input and what should be output can help.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the data?  If so, what part of `1 2 3 1 3 7 2 1 6 4 3 8` do you want in the `c[i][j]` array?

Comment: Oh, the data doesn't look right. it should be like 1 2 3, 1 3 7, 2 1 6...I should make it in different lines...there are three numbers in a line and no comma.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Its basically the same, but I added also parsing methods. You can parse each line using "split" and then you can easily convert it to integer by valueOf method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    processFile("words.txt");
}

public static void processFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    int[][] array = new int[4][3];
    int lineCount = 0;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                array[lineCount][i] = Integer.valueOf(parts[i]);
            }
            lineCount++;
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this will help!

Answer (score 0):

If the input is guaranteed to be 3 numbers (integers, not floating point), separated by 2 spaces, then you can use this.

If the input will be variable or untrustworthy then you can add more checks before parsing.

```
private static ArrayList<Integer[]> list;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    processFile("words.txt");
}

public static void processFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NumberFormatException
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    String line = null;

    list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

    while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] split = line.split("\\s{1}");

        list.add(
            new Integer[]
                {
                    Integer.parseInt(split[0]), 
                    Integer.parseInt(split[1]), 
                    Integer.parseInt(split[2]),
                });
    }
}
```

Although, you should technically be doing it like this:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer[]> list;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    processFile("words.txt");
}

public static void processFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NumberFormatException
{
    BufferedReader in = null;

    String line = null;

    list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

    try
    {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] split = line.split("\\s{1}");

            list.add(
                new Integer[]
                    {
                        Integer.parseInt(split[0]), 
                        Integer.parseInt(split[1]), 
                        Integer.parseInt(split[2]),
                    });
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(in != null)
        {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```